# How to parse &amp to & in vue with data from the database

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I ran into an issue where the data in my database is stored as **What is your favorite Play & Earn Mechanic?**

When I display it on my Frontend Vue application, it would display **&amp** as it is...  How can I make it to display as **&**

Comment: What do you receive from your backend? Encoded or not? Check your network tab to see where the issue is coming from. (probably the backend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you insert the content?

If you get content from your API/DB which is html encoded you need to inject the html first via v-html directive.

For example having a string:

```
"Im a Html Encoded <b>string</b> &amp; I want to be displayed"
```

You you pass it in your html  like this:

```
{{ "Im a Html Encoded <b>string</b> &amp; I want to be displayed" }}
```

It will be display as you read it here.

But if you do it like this:

```
<span v-html="'Im a Html Encoded <b>string</b> &amp; I want to be displayed'"></span>
```

Its displayed correctly. Have a look here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html

Also read the security warning there - if you allow HTML youre vulnerable to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Please don't recommend `v-html` for this. Overkill and not needed for such use-case.

Comment: @kissu , if we don't use v-html which alternative would you recommend?

Comment: @IdontEvenEven send that properly from the backend rather than doing hacks on the client-side.